# echo -n not working with secondary operation

Tags: echo, cut

I have a few filenames in a directory

```
blabla.01
blabla.02
...
```

I'm trying to make a new file with the following format:

```
01 new stuff here
02 more new stuff
...
```

I wrote a script and dumbed it down a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(find . -type f -name "blabla*" | awk -F'[.]' '$(NF-1)>=1' | sort)
for f in $FILES
do
    echo -n $f | cut -d "." -f 3
    echo "test"  
done
```

the 'test' will be the output of another code..
However in this example i get something like:

```
01
test02
test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printf '%s%s\n' "$(echo "$f" | cut -d . -f3)" "test"
```

The `echo | cut` could probably be replaced with something like `"${f##*.}"` if you always want the laat field.

Comment: Thanks, and what if I wanted to replace "test" with the text found in a single line file?

Comment: `"$(cat test)"` would seem like an easy way to include that.